# When I open a csv or excel file on excel the dates are in format Oct 20, 2020 12:58 PM but does not recognize them as dates. What can I do?

Tags: excel, csv, date

I would really like to know what to change in my system preferences to get excel to see dates as dates and not text "Oct 20, 2020 12:58 PM" like this one.

Comment: If they are stored as text, you'll have to convert them. A formula should be enouth. [DATE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/date-function-e36c0c8c-4104-49da-ab83-82328b832349), [LEFT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/left-leftb-functions-9203d2d2-7960-479b-84c6-1ea52b99640c), [MID](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mid-midb-functions-d5f9e25c-d7d6-472e-b568-4ecb12433028), [RIGHT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/right-rightb-functions-240267ee-9afa-4639-a02b-f19e1786cf2f) [...]

Comment: and [FIND](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-findb-functions-c7912941-af2a-4bdf-a553-d0d89b0a0628) should allow you to achieve your goal. Need any extra help?

Comment: **Import** instead of **Open**

Comment: import your csv with the [Get&Transform](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unified-get-transform-experience-ad78befd-eb1c-4ea7-a55d-79d1d67cf9b3) built-in feature of Excel (2016+)